# Can I calculate 4 distinct groups in SQL for my set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the problem below, which I have to solve in SQL. The database runs on SQL-Server 2005.
For one set (year and number) the group is supposed to be unique, e.g. in the set below I should have 4 groups (1 - 4) instead of groups ( 1-2).
I am not allowed to update the table and I cannot make fixes to the application.

Can I calculate 4 distinct group for my set, or is there a different way to solve the problem?

```
year    |number |row    |group<br>
2004    |1000   |1  |1<br>
2004    |1000   |2  |1<br>
2004    |1000   |3  |1<br>
2004    |1000   |4  |1<br>
2004    |1000   |5  |2<br>
2004    |1000   |6  |2<br>
2004    |1000   |7  |2<br>
2004    |1000   |8  |2<br>
2004    |1000   |9  |1<br>
2004    |1000   |10 |1<br>
2004    |1000   |11 |1<br>
2004    |1000   |12 |1<br>
2004    |1000   |13 |2<br>
2004    |1000   |14 |2<br>
2004    |1000   |15 |2<br>
2004    |1000   |16 |2<br>
```

Comment: Can you add your desired output??

Comment: rows 9 - 12 should have group 3 and rows 13-16 should have group 4. Gordon Linoffs solution does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can use window functions.  For this particular problem, you can use arithmetic on row number.  For the more general solution, this is a "gaps-and-islands" problem.  In SQL Server 2005, you can solve this using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by year, number order by group, seqnum_r - seqnum_rg) as grp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year, number order by row) as seqnum_r,
             row_number() over (partition by year, number, group order by row) as seqnum_rg
      from t
     ) t;
```

Understanding why this works is a bit tricky.  The important point is that the difference between the two sequence numbers is constant for the "islands" of similar values.  The `dense_rank()` then just provides the final value.

The above will produce four groups, but they may not be in the right order.  For that, use another round of window functions to get the minimum `id`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by year, number order by minid) as grp
from (select t.*, min(id) over (partition by year, number, group, seqnum_r - seqnum_rg) as minid
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by year, number order by row) as seqnum_r,
                   row_number() over (partition by year, number, group order by row) as seqnum_rg
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand your solution yet, but it works! I will defininetly research the point you mentioned (gaps and islands). Also I will have to look into the over clause and DENSE_RANK.